# using two different network internet and office server

Tags: networking, microsoft-office

I have one cable on Pc. If I want to access internet I have to change Ip Address and if I want to run any Accounting Software, I have to change Ip back again to connect to server. is there any chance that I can run both simultaneously without the need of changing Ip Address every time.

Comment: Why exactly do you need to do this? What's the setup? How are you changing IP addresses? We need more details

Comment: When I want to use internet I will go to internet protocol 4 and select obtain an Ip address automatically. But when I want to login into any oracle program installed on my Pc i require access to server. So I go to Ipv4 and manually enter the Ip Address, Default gateway and DNS.

Comment: Still not enough information.  You give almost nothing to work with other than "something" is wrong and you are changing the IP address to make "something" work.  To help, we need to know what the "somethings" are.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are changing proxy setting, not IP. To ease changing of proxy you can install proxy switchy in chrome browser, can be installed from chrome extensions.

Comment: No its Ip address..When I want to use internet I will go to internet protocol 4 and select obtain an Ip address automatically. But when I want to login into any oracle program installed on my Pc i require access to server. So I go to Ipv4 and manually enter the Ip Address, Default gateway and DNS